# WooCommerce API Returns 401

Tags: multisite, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-api

very confused by how the rest api for WooComm is functioning.

I understand how it should function, but it returns a 401 no matter what I do. My user is a super admin and has read/write permissions.

I've tried both:

```
curl -k https://seekmodern.local/wp-json/wc/v2/products? 
consumer_key=ck_***&consumer_secret=cs_***
```

and

```
curl -k https://seekmodern.local/wp-json/wc/v2/products -u 
ck_***:cs_***
```

I've confirmed with my hosting provider and the docs this should be all I need. The API itself works (https://seekmodern.local/wp-json/wc/v2/) so I know this api is active. The auth bit is totally failing though. I've tried enabling/disabling all plugins too and it still seems to be broken. Anything obvious I might be missing here? This is very confusing and the docs suggest it should be very simple.

I'm just looking for basic auth here, I know OAuth is supported, but I'm not in need of that at the moment.

The site is a multisite network, but there should be no issue enabling the API for each individual child site correct?

Answer (score 0):

So for whatever reason, I could get it to work on my instance on wpengine, but not my local. I'd have to assume this is something to with the way my local is configured. thanks.